# take data from 3 tables using orderby

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables(event_csv,TimeSlots and FilledSlots). i have to check whether 'Quota' represents total no seats with $filledpositions(no.of filled seats) then after i want to sort out the rows in 'event_csv' table in the order of unfilled rows displaying first

```
   SELECT csv_id,description,Location_description,Jobdate FROM event_csv WHERE Jobdate = '$event';

   SELECT ID, Quota, StartTime, EndTime FROM TimeSlots WHERE EventID='. $row[csv_id] . ';

   $filledquery = 'SELECT ID FROM FilledSlots WHERE TimeSlotID=' . $filled[ID];
   $filledresult = mysql_query($filledquery) or die(mysql_error());
   $filledPositions =  mysql_num_rows($filledresult);
```

event_csv table have following fields

```
    1   csv_id  int(11)             
2   TaskId  int(12)             
3   description     varchar(32)         
4   super   char(32)    
5   LocId   int(8)              
6   Location_description    varchar(32)         
7   Jobdate     date            
8   Jobtime     time                
9   Duration    time            
10  PersonsReq  int(2)          
11  tshirt  varchar(3)      
12  counted     int(1)
```

TimeSlots table have following fields

```
    1   ID  int(11)             
2   Date    date            
3   Quota   int(11)             
4   EventID     int(11)         
5   SlotName    varchar(64)     
6   StartTime   time            
7   EndTime     time            
8   beer_hours  int(2)
```

FilledSlots table have following fields

```
1   ID  int(11)             
2   TimeSlotID  int(11)                     
3   EventID     int(11)             
4   VolName     varchar(80)     
5   VolEmail    varchar(150)        
6   VolPhone    varchar(15)     
7   Shirt_Size  varchar(32)     
8   Approved    tinyint(1)      
9   Time_slot   time            
10  beer_hours  int(2)
```

Comment: Please tell us how we can help you

Comment: how to sort out the rows

Comment: please explain in more detail with all the fields of your 3 tables..

Comment: still not getting please explain in detail... (FULL DETAIL)

Comment: This query for displaying event details based on date and display unfilled seats first.'Quota' in TimeSlots table represents total number of seats and mysql_num_rows($filledresult) return number of filled seats.i want to sort out the rows in 'event_csv' table in the order of unfilled rows displaying first